# Display activity on 2 android devices simultaneously over a network

Tags: java, android, networking

I have to create a simple single and multiplayer game in android about tilting the phone and recording the quickest time in a certain direction. I have successfully managed to create the single player version in Java. However I have no clue where to start with the multiplayer option where the game starts simultaneously on both devices where one is a server and the other the client (decided beforehand by the 2 people). I did take a look at the Android p2p website, but it wasn't much help. I have used **Android Studio** for the project.

I have all the math and logic ready from the single player, I am only struggling to how I can start the multiplayer by displaying an activity on 2 separate devices simultaneously. Unfortunately I don't have code to show for multiplayer as I have no idea where to begin.

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How are the devices communicating?  Can their times be synchronized and used to start the activities at the same time?

Comment: I believe so. But I was thinking of maybe using WiFi-Direct to create a connection with the device, and then maybe somehow finding the server on the client device and connect it, and then start the simultaneous activity. But I got lost on how to start with that.

Comment: I had good luck with code from this site: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/